# Javascript - IndexOf is returning random numbers

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to generate a random number between 1-75, then compare it to an array so that I can later use the result as an argument for an if / else statement; (i.e., if the number is in the array, do this, otherwise do that.)

Here is the relevant code:

```
var pickable = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75];

var grid = [7,14,8,10,4,25,18,20,26,27,37,33,40,45,32,48,55,49,52,53,61,63,74,73,67];

function pick()
{
    var temp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pickable.length));      
    var temp2 = temp1.toString();                                   
    var check = grid.indexOf(temp2);                                

    alert (check + "\n"  + grid);
}
```

But this code isn't giving me index numbers that make sense;  It returns -1 when the number is clearly in the array, returns other numbers for numbers that are not in the array, or returns a number that has no obvious relationship to the position of the number in the array.  Why is this not working, and what would work better?  Please keep in mind, I'm just learning to code, so detailed explanations are appreciated.

---

After a bit of experimenting, I've found that what it is doing is picking the random number, writing it to the appropriate places on the screen, then subtracting the number of iterations of the loop before using that number to check the index.  (I think.)  In other words, the first time I cick the button, it displays 48 on the screen, but searches the index for 47.  The next time I click the button it displays 56, but searches for 54, etc.  Here is the entire function:

```
function pick()
{
    if (pickable.length > 0)
    {
        var temp1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pickable.length));      
        var temp2 = temp1.toString();                                   
        var check = grid.indexOf(temp2);                                
        alert ("index: " + check + "\nball: " + temp1 + "\n");

        document.getElementById("ballNum").innerHTML = pickable[temp1]; 
        pickable[temp1] = pickable[0];                                  
        pickable.shift();                                               
        picked.push(document.getElementById("ballNum").innerHTML);      
        document.getElementById("pickedNums").innerHTML = picked.join("| "); 
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You are out of Bingo balls! \nPlease start over by clicking the " + 
        " \n\"Populate Board\" button.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a string, and the array contains numbers.

Comment: Use the `temp1` number, not the string: `var check = grid.indexOf(temp1);`

Comment: The -1 makes sense, that is how `indexOf` indicates the value wasn't found. The rest of your claims, that `indexOf` "returns other numbers for numbers that are not in the array/numbers that have no obvious relationship to the position of the number in the array", that is you misinterpreting what you're seeing. You're going to have to provide some more concrete proof of this behaviour for us to have any hope of explaining it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your array contains integers (whole numbers), but you are trying to find numbers represented as Strings (sequences of characters). That won't work because the integer  2 is not the same as the String "2". If you leave out the toString line, and check for the index of temp1, your code should work as you expect. In this form it should only ever return - 1 - I think you are mistaken about other return values.

Comment: What's the `pickable` for? To get a random number between 1 and 75 you just need `Math.floor(Math.random() * 75) + 1` (basically what you did for `temp1`).

Comment: I hope you wrote a program to generate the list of pickable numbers :-)

Comment: Hmmm.  I added the toString line because everything was coming back as -1.  I assumed it was because the numbers in the array were strings.  (In the actual code, the numbers are being automatically generated by another function.  I don't know if that makes a difference.)  I'm using the pickable array to do a Fischer-Yates shuffle.